# To prove $xx_{0} + yy_{0} = r ^ { 2 }$

Tags: circles

There is a circle ($x ^ {2} + y ^ {2} = r ^ { 2 }$), there is a point P ($x_{0}$, $y_{0}$) outside the circle, there are two lines tangent to the circle through the point P, and the tangent points are A($x_{1}$,$y_{1}$) and B($x_{2},y_{2}$) respectively. How do I prove that AB's linear equation is

$xx_{0} + yy_{0} = r ^ { 2 }$

(This question has been translated by machine)

My teacher gave me the solution is:

Because the point P is on two tangents

–>

So we have:

$x_{1}x_{0} + y_{1}y_{0} = r ^ { 2 }$

$x_{2}x_{0} + y_{2}y_{0} = r ^ { 2 }$

Then

$xx_{0} + yy_{0} = r ^ { 2 }$

I can't understand it.

Comment: $x_{1}x_{0} + y_{1}y_{0} = r ^ { 2 }$ and $x_{2}x_{0} + y_{2}y_{0} = r ^ { 2 }$ are as though the Eq. of AB is $ xx_0+yy_0=r^2$ and AB is passing through the points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$.

Comment: Why can the point P be written as $ x _ { 1 } x _ { 0 } +y _ { 1 } y _ { 0 } = r^ { 2 } $, have I forgotten some knowledge of circles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that slope of tangent$=\frac{dy}{dx}$.
Here differentiating both sides of the equation we get $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-x}{y}$.So equation of tangent passing through the point $(x_1,y_1)$ is
$$y-y_1=-\frac{x_1}{y_1}(x-x_1)$$
$$\Rightarrow xx_1+yy_1=x_{1}^2+y_{1}^2=r^2$$
Similarly for $(x_2,y_2)$
Now since $(x_0,y_0)$ lies on both the tangents you can get the two equations that your teachers gave by plugging the coordinates.

.....

Comment: Oh,thanks!I got it:D

Answer (score 0):

AB is the chord of contact of the circle $x^2+y^2=r^2$ about the point P$(x_0,y_0)$.

Eq. of tangent to the circle at [pint A$(x_1,y_1)$ is $x_1x+y_1y=r^2$ as this passes through the point P, we have

$x_1x_0+y_1y_0=r^2....(1)$.

Next the Eq. of tangent to the same circle at point B$(x_2,y_2)$ is $x_2x+y_2y=r^2$ as this also passes through the point P, we have

$x_2 x_0+y_2 y_0=r^2.....(2)$

Eq. (1,2) are as though the equation of the line AB is $x_0x+y_0y=r^2$ and it passes through the points A and B, respectively.

Comment: Hmmm,someone explained to me the above do not understand the place, for your answer I am still confused, but thank you for your answer :D，I love this place so much.